# grep not working when I enclose the directory in double quotes

Tags: linux, grep, quoting, wildcards

When I do something like this:

```
grep "hello" /home/paul/*
```

It works.

But when I do something like this:

```
grep "hello" "/home/paul/*"
```

`grep` display the error:

> grep: /home/paul/*: No such file or sirectory

Why is that?

Comment: You can do single quotes as well. `grep 'home/paul/*'`

Comment: see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: @Jesse_b - has the appropriate, well-cited answer; but just to place a term with the concept -> here is the [Pathname expansion](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bash/bash.1.en.html#Pathname_Expansion) section from the bash manpage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the bash reference manual:

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’.

So you must remove the special character `*` from your quoted string in order for it to be treated as a wildcard.

```
grep "hello" "/home/paul/"*
```